# python-requests - Sending via POST form with square brackets names doesn't work

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I'm trying to send test[key1] = val1 and test[key2] = val42 to the server via an HTML form.
The corresponding HTML would be:

```
<input type="text" name="test[key1]" value="val1" />
<input type="text" name="test[key2]" value="val42" />
```

(By the way, I would like to know the correct name for this kind of form.)

```
>>> import requests, json
>>> params = { 'test' : { 'key1' : 'val1', 'key2' : 'val42' } }
>>> r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data=params)
>>> json.loads(r.text)['form']
{u'test': [u'key2', u'key1']}
```

The post data has been flattened, we get the keys but lost the values val1 and val42

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I thought [python-requests](http://python-requests.org) would handle automatically the params json with embedded keys, that is not the case.

You need to write `params` with the square brackets.

```
>>> params = { 'test[key1]' : 'val1', 'test[key2]' : 'val42' }
>>> r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data=params)
>>> json.loads(r.text)['form']
{u'test[key1]': u'val1', u'test[key2]': u'val42'}
```

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

HTML forms by default cannot be serialized as they don't support nesting. Use a library like `formencode`, especially the `variabledecode` module to serialize/deserialize the form data to json.

https://github.com/formencode/formencode/blob/master/formencode/variabledecode.py