# Force requests.get to use square brackets without percent encoding in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, python-requests

I am using an API with some awful documentation and to query data within a date range I have to use square brackets. Percent encoding them does not work. It needs to be in the following format according to their documentation:

```
https://catalogue.onda-dias.eu/dias-catalogue/Products/$count?$search="beginPosition:[2019-04-15T00:00:00.000Z%20TO%202019-10-15T00:00:00.000Z]"
```

This should return the count of datasets that fall within this daterange.

When I put this string into postman or in a browser it works perfectly  and returns:

```
8005988
```

But I need to automate this process in python and when I try:

```
url = 'https://catalogue.onda-dias.eu/dias-catalogue/Products/$count?$search=%22beginPosition:[2019-04-15T00:00:00.000Z%20TO%202019-10-15T00:00:00.000Z]%20AND%20productType:IW_GRDH_1S%20AND%20footprint:%22Intersects(POLYGON((-67.9381325%2047.2170167,%20-67.8915617%2046.0090853,%20-67.3414435%2046.0207280,%20-67.3414435%2046.0207280,%20-67.9381325%2047.2170167)))%22%22'

auth = (username, password) # for this URL you don't need a username or password to view the result but do later when you need to download,

resp = requests.get(
        url=url,
        auth=auth,
    )

print(resp.json())
print(resp.request.url)
```

I get this error saying that it doesn't like square brackets

```
{'error': {'code': None, 'message': "Exception during tokenizer creation with message 'Forbidden character in state PHRASE->['."}}
```

and this is the printed URL:

```
https://catalogue.onda-dias.eu/dias-catalogue/Products/$count?$search=%22beginPosition:%5B2019-04-15T00:00:00.000Z%20TO%202019-10-15T00:00:00.000Z%5D%22
```

I get the same error if I replace [ and ] with %5B and %5D in the URL string.

Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490771/python-requests-sending-via-post-form-with-square-brackets-names-doesnt-work/23490772

Comment: This is the response from the server. I guess the url string badly formed.